# Function call as iterable in for of loop ES6

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

Looking for best practice advice.

Is it a good practice to have function call in *for of* as iterable object?

```
const obj = {key1:'a', key2:'b'};

for(const i of Object.keys(obj)){ ... }
```

or better to have

```
const obj = {key1:'a', key2:'b'};
const allKeys = Object.keys(obj);
for(const i of allKeys){ ... }
```

Isn't Object.keys function called on every iteration of the loop?

Comment: They're equivalent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can check it by mocking a similar case

```js
function A(){
    console.log('function called');
    return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
}

for(let i of A()){
    console.log(i);
}
```

As you can see A() is called only once

Comment: You *can*, sure, but it's better to have an understanding of what's actually happening.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example does the same thing as the second, just without the `allKeys` constant. In your first example:

```
const obj = {key1:'a', key2:'b'};

for(const i of Object.keys(obj)){ ...
```

...`Object.keys` will only get called *once*, and then its iterator will be retrieved and used for the loop. (This is covered in [ForIn/OfHeadEvaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofheadevaluation-tdznames-expr-iterationkind) in the spec, but it's...heavy going.) So you're fine using that form, it's not inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `Object.keys` is only made once in both variants.

But consider also as possibility this `for` loop that does not depend on `Object.keys`:

```
for (const prop in obj) {  }
```

`Object.keys` creates an array, while the above `for` loop does not. The latter only retrieves the items as necessary. Of course, if your `for` loop is never exited prematurely, it will still retrieve all of them, so this only makes a difference when you plan to exit the loop prematurely. In that case the corresponding iterator never *visits* the remaining items, while `Object.keys` would already have done so in creating the array.

One thing to pay attention to: a `for .. in` loop will also iterate enumerable *inherited* properties, not only *own* properties, while `Object.keys` will only list *own* enumerable properties. You can add an extra test in the `for` loop to exclude non-own properties:

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
```

Comment: Should of course be `in`, not `of`. Thanks for mentioning, @T.J.Crowder.

Comment: Ah....of course. For some reason I didn't twig to that. I suggest calling out the difference re inherited properties.

Comment: I'm curious about your assertion that "the above `for` loop does not [create an array]", and "only retrieves the items as necessary". Of course it does not create an actual array, but I suspect most or all engines would prepare an internal list of all keys--wouldn't they?